# An error is displayed when I try to create my Android project

Tags: java, android, user-interface, kotlin, gradle

When I try to create an new Android project init Android studio it gives me this error message "Fatal error initializing plugin gradle gui". How can I resolve it

Comment: Honestly I'd just try to reinstall Android Studio

Comment: Attach image of your error please. Where do you get that error?

Comment: Can you elaborate your issue and maybe include an image of the error